# css width 0 and overflow hidden issue in safari

Tags: html, css, safari

I have encountered what I consider a bug in Safari and was wondering if anyone might be able to shed some light on why this outcome is taking place. I have included a very simple example below, but basically my issue is this. I have a child element with a width of 300px and a height of 80px, I have a this child nested in a parent with a width of 0px and an overflow that is hidden. These two elements are wrapped in a container that has no width set and all three elements are floated left. The content is being hidden by the parent, however the container that is wrapping them both is extending the full width of the "hidden" child. Works great in every browser except Safari and I don't know why.

summary: width: 0px; and overflow: hidden; does not work in safari

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
   #container {background: rgba(0,0,255,1); float: left;}
   #block {width: 0px; background: rgba(255,0,0,0.50); float: left; overflow: hidden;}
   #content {width: 300px; height: 80px; background: rgba(0,255,0,0.50);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
   <div id="block">
      <div id="content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copy and paste the block above into an html page. View that page in Safari, Chrome and Firefox. You will see a blue 300x80 rectangle in Safari, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

> Certain display values seem to be where the bug happens in Safari.

After a lot of trial and error it seems that a good solution may be setting `max-width` to the same as `width`. Keep in mind that if you animate `width` you need to set `max-width` to something that allows `width` to expand (possibly a value of `auto`), temporarily, while the animation occurs.

Read the various **CSS comments** below to understand more about this problem.

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="block">
    sfdklhgfdlkbgjhdlkjdhbgflkjbhgflkdfgid
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS:

```css
#container {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  background: red;
  /* BUG: Certain display values seem to be where the bug happens, if display was just inline here, there would be no issue. */
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: dotted 2px green;
}

#block {
  width: 0;
  /* height: 0; Setting height to 0 simply creates the illusion that width is fixed. If you look at the border, the width is still there, so height 0 does not help. */
  background: blue;
  /* BUG: Certain display values seem to be where the bug happens, if you don't need this, change it. */
  display: inline-flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Has no practical effect here. */
  text-overflow: clip;
  /* font-size: 0; still keeps a little bit of width and can spoil the look of animating the width open from 0. */
  /* margin-right: -100vw; is a nasty hack that totally works but is bad for animating margins. */
  /* BEST FIX: Setting this property to the same as width may be the best way to fix the issue. */
  max-width: 0;
}
```

Running example at: https://jsfiddle.net/resistdesign/k0b5s4p7

Answer (score 1):

> If you are presentnig text inside that div. Then, you should try to zero font-size.

```
.class{
 font-size:0;
 }
```

> Or use text-indent

.class{
      text-indent: -999px
  }

Comment: I am not presenting text. If you have a look at the example above, Safari basically disables overflow: hidden; on an element if it's width is 0.

Comment: @deathtrap This is safari bug. If the above options will work for you that's fine. Other then i can't have much to offer as i am a PC guy and not bother much safari.

Answer (score 0):

If you also set `height: 0;` on `#block` your problem will be solved. Not sure why this is happening though :/